# AngularJs, Bootstrap, popup error

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

Can any one tell me why me popup is not working? I have used table sorter in Angularjs, but when the link is clicked on the popup is not getting displayed.

Test1.html

```
<div ng-controller="DemoCtrl">
<table ng-table="tableParams" class="table table-striped 
 table-condensed table-hover"     border ="1">
    <tr ng-repeat="user in $data">
        <td data-title="'Event Id'" sortable="'event_id'">
         <div ng-contorller="MyCtrl">
        <a href="#"  ng-click='toggleModal()'>{{user.name}} </a>

        <modal-dialog show='modalShown' width='400px' height='60%'>
  <p>Modal Content Goes here</p>
</modal-dialog>
        </div>

        </td>
        <td data-title="'Event Date & Time'" sortable="'event_date'">
            {{user.age}}
        </td>
          <td data-title="'Event Type'" sortable="'event_type'">
            {{user.age}}
        </td>
          <td data-title="'Serverity'" sortable="'serverity'">
            {{user.age}}
        </td>
          <td data-title="'Device Name'" sortable="'device_name'">
            {{user.age}}
        </td>
          <td data-title="'User Name'" sortable="'user_name'">
            {{user.age}}
        </td>
          <td data-title="'Mail Sent Time'" sortable="'mail_sent'">
            {{user.age}}
        </td>
          <td data-title="'Mail Status'" sortable="'mail_status'">
            {{user.age}}
        </td>
          <td data-title="'Remarks'" sortable="'remarks'">
            {{user.age}}
        </td>
    </tr>

    </table>
</div>
</div>
```

script.js

```
var app = angular.module('main', ['ngTable']);
app.directive('modalDialog', function() {
          return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
              show: '='
            },
            replace: true, // Replace with the template below
            transclude: true, // we want to insert custom content 
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
              scope.dialogStyle = {};

              if (attrs.width)
                scope.dialogStyle.width = attrs.width;

              if (attrs.height)
                scope.dialogStyle.height = attrs.height;
              scope.hideModal = function() {
                scope.show = false;
              };
            },
            template: "<div class='ng-modal' ng-show='show'>
    <div  class='ng-modal-overlay' ng-click='hideModal()'></div>
  <div class='ng-modal-dialog' ng-style='dialogStyle'>
  <div class='ng-modal-close' ng-click='hideModal()'>X</div>
  <div class='ng-modal-dialog-content' ng-transclude></div></div></div>"
          };
        });
  app.controller('DemoCtrl', function($scope, $filter, ngTableParams) {
  var data = [{name: "Moroni", age: 50},
            {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
            {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
            {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
            {name: "Enos", age: 34},
            {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
            {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
            {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
            {name: "Enos", age: 34},
            {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
            {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
            {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
            {name: "Enos", age: 34},
            {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
            {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
            {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
            {name: "Enos", age: 34}];
$scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
    page: 1,            // show first page
    count: 10,          // count per page
    sorting: {
        name: 'asc'     // initial sorting
    }
}, {
    total: data.length, // length of data
    getData: function($defer, params) {
        // use build-in angular filter
        var orderedData = params.sorting() ?
                            $filter('orderBy')(data, params.orderBy()) :
                            data;
        $defer.resolve(orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1)
      * params.count(),       params.page() * params.count()));
    }
   });
 });
  app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
          $scope.modalShown = false;
          $scope.toggleModal = function() {
          alert(1);
            $scope.modalShown = !$scope.modalShown;
          };
        }]);
```

Comment: can you please [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net) it

Comment: do you at least see the alert? `alert(1);` of your code...

Comment: Yes,I do see alert .It's like the moment I run program ,i see alert plus my popup content bt when I refreshe nothing will appear.

Comment: Here.it is: http://jsfiddle.net/p6zzV/

Comment: I could solve the problem.There was  problem wid controller.